# Asp .Net Core Fail to delete file during publish using File System

Tags: asp.net-core

I am deploying to IIS using file system but i get error on deleting the current dll files on iis folder.

I read that the app needs to add the app_offline.html file to do this and that i need to add

```
  <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
  <EnableMSDeployAppOffline>True</EnableMSDeployAppOffline>
```

somewhere when using filesystem. I can't find any information about this tho, i tried doing it on csproj file but no luck.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/visual-studio-publish-profiles?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Answer (score 1):

The `<EnableMSDeployAppOffline>` requires Web Deploy. If you're doing a filesystem publish, it's not going to have any effect. You need to either publish via Web Deploy, or manually stop the App Pool, move the files, and then start it up again.